# Extended Class And implemented interface having same method name

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java, if I have a `ClassA` that extends a `ClassX` and implements an `InterfaceY`, and both `ClassX` and `InterfaceY` have a `methodC()`, then why don't I have to give an implementation of `methodC()` in `ClassA`? Is it some kind of method overloading ?

Answer (score 2):

Because if `ClassX` has an implementation of `methodC()` and `ClassA` extends `ClassX`, then `ClassA` *does* have an implementation of `methodC()` - `ClassX`'s implementation of it.

If `ClassA` has it's own implementation of `methodC()`, that would be called method *overriding* - `ClassA`'s implementation would *override* the implementation of its super class (`ClassX`).

*Overloading* is a different issue entirely: Overloading occurs when a class has multiple methods with the same name/return type that take different parameters. This is useful when you want to be able to perform the same or similar operations with different inputs, and it has nothing to do with *overriding*, which is useful when you have a subclass whose implementation of a particular method needs to be different than that of its super-class.

See [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/method-overriding-vs-overloading) for a helpful discussion about the differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple,

actually when you extend the class all non private attributes and methods gets inherited to sub class.

so in your case

```
class X{

//method C implemented here
}

interface Y{
//method c declaration
}

class A extends X implements Y{
//method C implemented here comes from class X
}
```

so no need to provide it again.

Comment: That is what I guessed but doesn't that beat the purpose of the fact that we have to implement all the methods in interface...